# How to check if an element is a script

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome

I'm gathering a random element from the DOM with javascript. How can I check something likewise "if element is a script, do something" ()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do it, depending on the level of robustness you need.

If you only deal with DOM elements of an `<!DOCTYPE html>` document then the following is enough:

```
if (el.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
}
```

Note that since `el.tagName` is [not always guaranteed to be in upper-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223756/is-element-tagname-always-uppercase) for all doctypes you may want:

```
if (el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'SCRIPT') {
}
```

If you're not sure which type of object you're dealing with, you can still use duck typing:

```
if (el && el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'SCRIPT') {
}
```

Or make an even stricter check in modern browsers with:

```
if (el instanceof HTMLScriptElement) {
}
```

Comment: When accidentally checking the "document" as element it triggered error for lack of "tagName", i used this `Object.getPrototypeOf(element).toString() === "[object HTMLScriptElement]"`

Comment: @ion Updated the answer.