# Is Element.tagName always uppercase?

Tags: javascript

Reading at [MDN about Element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) it states:

> On HTML elements in DOM trees flagged as HTML documents, tagName returns the element name in the uppercase form.

My question is: is this trustable? Does IE (old and modern) behave as expected? Is this likely to change? or is it better to always work with `el.tagName.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: `n XML (and XML-based languages such as XHTML), tagName preserves case.` so if, for example, in doctype you set xhtml - tagName will preserve case

Comment: @LeoDeng this was quotation from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName)

Comment: I did test and that's not true. I've updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: tagName is lowercase for SVG [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6rpox8y/)

Comment: @VenkataRaju `:o`!!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You don't have to `toLowerCase` or whatever, browsers do behave the same on this point (surprisingly huh?).

About the rationale, once I had discussion with a colleague who's very professional on W3C standards. One of his opinions is that using uppercase TAGNAME would be much easier to recognize them out of user content. That's quite persuasive for me.

---

**Edit:** As @adjenks says, XHTML doctype returns mixed-case tagName *if the document is served as `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`*. Test page: http://programming.enthuses.me/tag-node-case.php?doc=x

Technically, please read this spec for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614

> Note that this (tagName) is **case-preserving in XML**, as are all of the operations of the DOM. The HTML DOM returns the tagName of an HTML element in the canonical uppercase form, regardless of the case in the source HTML document.

As of asker's question: this is trustable. Breaking change is not likely to happen in HTML spec.

Comment: I thought the whole point of XHTML was to switch from using SGML to XML. In fact, most browsers bail (or at least used to back when it first came out) when the XHTML was invalid XML.

Comment: @Alex Obviously you are not talking about XHTML 2.0, which is dead now. It shows no mercy if the syntax isn't 100% correct.

Comment: @Leo -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223756/is-element-tagname-always-uppercase?noredirect=1#comment67646909_27223756

Comment: @Rikard Good catch man! SVG is regarded as embedded XML document, so it follows the XML spec, which is all lower case. You had me :D

Comment: @Rikard Literally, if you were asking about the **HTML** spec and how the vendors implement (which is also what I supposed to answer), then my original answer is correct. If you are from an engineering perspective, mixed namespaces do mess it up.

Comment: I discovered Firefox 54.0 returning lowercase tag names when the document was dynamically loaded as xhtml with all the correct xhtml headers. It really confused me at first.

Comment: Why can I not edit the post to correct the discovery I noted above?

Comment: @adjenks How did you do that? If the document was treated as XML, the tags should be in lower cases. Here we are talking about HTML tags.

Comment: @Leo If you are specifically talking about HTML only, that is fine. However XHTML is a subset of XML and is valid HTML as well (https://www.google.ca/search?q=html+xml+venn+diagram&tbm=isch#imgrc=lxa358k6SfOhOM:). I believe it's valid point to make since some people, including myself are working on XHTML projects. I wanted to specifically disagree with where you state "edit: As some say xhtml doctype returns lowercase tagName, I did tests - the result is UPPERCASE. And by the way, XHTML is XML-style HTML, it's still HTML, not XML."

Comment: @adjenks could you provide a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @Leo Here is a link to a website demonstrating a tag that returns a mixture of upper and lowercase: http://gofiddleyourself.jelikraft.ca/27223756/is-element-tagname-always-uppercase
The reason it renders the page as XHTML and not just HTML is because the Content-Type is set to `application/xhtml+xml` which is the correct content type for an XHTML document. Few people actually set their content type when developing web pages which is why they do not notice lowercase tags when parsing their documents.

Comment: I could not use a jsfiddle because jsfiddle does not allow you to set the HTTP headers. If anyone wants to read more about XHTML and how it is processed, a good article can be found here: www.dev-archive.net/articles/xhtml.html

Answer (score 32):

In WebKit/Chromium it is not trustable, WebKit can create tagName properties also in lowercase, most of web pages builds uppercase tagName's, but it is also possible to build lowercase values, so if you use WebKit you must be prepare to support both cases.
I thought tagName's are allways uppercase(most of are) and I see I was wrong, now I must little fix my script :)

[chrome's inspector screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCM6i.png)

EDIT:
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAf9f.png)

Comment: Can you make a `console.log(element.tagName)` to confirm this? in that case would be a major backward compatibility break...

Comment: This needs more upvotes because it proves the accepted answer is not always correct.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035222/368254
It seems that SVG elements are lowercased in all major browsers.

Comment: The question is about *"DOM trees flagged as HTML documents"*.  This answer is definitely good to know about, but the accepted answer is still correct.

Answer (score 8):

`tagName` and `nodeName` comes in lowercase or case sensitive, in case page **response headers** is having `Content-type: application/xhtml+xml;` header or any xhtml related content type.
e.g. `document.documentElement.nodeName` returns `html`
Read this for more cases: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614

Comment: I experience this today. Really threw me off. Broke a function in my library.

Comment: I came to know about this issue while using jQuery and broke a function while matching a tagName.

Comment: Another test page, testing different HTML versions: http://programming.enthuses.me/tag-node-case.php?doc=x

Answer (score 6):

Work with `element.tagName.toLowerCase()` if your code requires the output in lower case.  If the standards change in the future to lowercase then you would not get a different value in your output since it's formatted to lowercase anyway.

On the contrary, if you left it without `toLowerCase()` then your code output can change if the standards are changed to output as lowercase.

I doubt the standard will change for this though. This is entirely up to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

My tests show that the `tagName` of SVG elements seems to be lowercase in all browsers I checked in August 2018 (Chrome 68, Firefox 61, Edge 42, IE11)

Not sure how that relates to the "DOM trees" mentioned in the MDN docs - maybe SVG trees are handled separately/differently despite of them being part of the DOM tree. 
In the end, developers do typically speak of "SVG elements" and "DOM elements", as in pointing out that they're not the same thing.

In any case, if your application needs to handle SVG elements as well as regular DOM elements, make sure to use `tagName.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: as @Leo mentioned in his answer: xml is case-preserving, and svg is an xml based format.

Answer (score -1):

when check this . I saw it also uupercase so

```js
if (e.target.tagName === "IMG"){
   e.target.parentElement.remove();
}
```

tried It.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).