# Why are svg tagNames lowercase and non-svg uppercase?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Why is one lowercase and the other uppercase ?

```js
console.log("standard :", document.getElementById('link').tagName)  // A

console.log("svg : ", document.getElementById('SvgLink').tagName)  // a
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="background: peachpuff;">
    <a id="SvgLink" href="http://perdu.com">
        <circle  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red"></circle>
    </a>
</svg>

<a id="link" href="http://perdu.com">Link</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Element.tagName always uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223756/is-element-tagname-always-uppercase)

Comment: It doesn't answer the why question !

Comment: MDN says, "For example, if the element is an <img>, its tagName property is 'IMG' (for HTML documents; it may be cased differently for XML/XHTML documents)." I suppose XML has something to do with it. Uppercase for HTML, lower for XML. Don't know why that difference though.

Comment: This is a nice read: https://johnresig.com/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/

Comment: So since the `<a>` is part of the `<svg>` namespace, the `tagName` is lowercase.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler [It pretty much does.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035222/4728913) But if you need to have it copy-pasted by someone else, have it your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG's original format was XML only. XML is case sensitive. Some of that case sensitivity remains for compatibility reasons when SVG is embedded within HTML documents.

See [DOM level 2 core](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) description of tagName

> ...Note that this is case-preserving in XML, as are all of the operations of the DOM...